# TimeZoneInfo Id is dependent on machines?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` in my code.

And I know this method works with ids are on the system registry.

So I'm wondering if there is any chance this wouldn't work correctly when it goes to server, because the ids on server's registry aren't same with my local's.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Why do you need the timezone IDs? They are very "unstable" - for example, some machine might not have the correct timezone updates, rendering different time for the same timezone on client and server. Can you just use UTC?

Comment: @DarkWanderer Because I will have servers and clients on different timezone like Austrailia and China. And the time should be displayed as client time not server time. And there would be also day light saving period which is changed continously, so for all of these, TimeZoneInfo could make it simple for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is *possible* that the ID won't be found (see the other answers), if both machines have current Windows Updates, then it is not *likely* you will have a mismatch.

Even then, while changes to the definitions for daylight saving time and display names occur multiple times per year, it is rare for entirely new time zones to be created, and the IDs will never change once established.

So as long as at least your *server* has the current Windows Updates for time zones, then you should be able to handle any valid input from the clients, even if they aren't as up to date.  You can review all the time zone updates for Windows on [this site](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cp_dst).

However, despite all of this, my best advice would be to give up using Microsoft time zones and use standard IANA time zones instead.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.  In .NET, the best way to achieve this is by using the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This clears my worries. I might still use Microsoft TimeZone if it doesn't have significant chance to fail. However I'll check Noda Time library.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeZone` stuff always confuses me but my answer is *YES*. There is a chance that wouldn't work in different servers.

[`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` registry information. And sometimes Microsoft release some windows updates to change these informations.

For example *[August 2012 cumulative time zone update for Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2732052)*;

> - E. Europe Standard Time: The display name for this time zone has been updated to "(UTC+2:00) E. Europe." from "(UTC+2:00) Nicosia."
> - Azores Standard Time: Changes the 2013 DST start time to occur at 12:00:00 AM on the last Sunday of March and end time to occur at
>     01:00:00 AM on the last Sunday of October.
> - Pacific SA Standard Time: As previously announced in Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2681116, Chile has extended the 2012 Daylight
>     Saving Time. The Chilean government has changed the 2012 DST start
>     date to occur on the first Saturday of September 23:59:59.999 and end
>     date to occur on the last Saturday of April at 23:59:59.999.

As you can see, one of your servers doesn't have the same information in their registry (one could not be updated for example), these `TimeZone` informations looks different.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN - TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the Id is not found you will get a [TimeZoneNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezonenotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The time zone identifier specified by id was not found. This means
>   that a registry key whose name matches id does not exist, or that the
>   key exists but does not contain any time zone data.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you need is conversion of server datetime to local client time (and not cross-client conversion) use UTC time in communications and `DateTime.ToLocal()` on client. Then you won't need to worry about registry or timezones at all.

Comment: But I need to consider daylight saving time which changed continuously too.

Comment: Think again - do you think computer's local time doesn't take dst into account?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. The client is the web browser so it can't do anything with DateTime.ToLocal(). And the server is stil on different timezone with client.

Comment: Cool, the question doesn't mention that it's a web application at all :-) Okay, the currently accepted answer is the way to go then, no arguments.